# How to show that $ E[\sum_{n=0}^{\tau-1}I[S_n=i]]=1 $ for any $i\in Z$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ be a sequence of Bernoulli random variables with $P(X_i=1)=p=1-P(X_i=-1)$. Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\tau_0=\inf\{t > 0: S_t=0\}$. How to show that
$$
E[\sum_{n=0}^{\tau-1}I[S_n=b]]=1
$$
for any $b\in \mathbb Z$? Here $I[\cdot]$ is the indicator function.

---

It seems that we need to use the optimal sampling theorem in martingale theroy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely misread what the problem was asking.  You should ignore my earlier comments, they are likely entirely incorrect.

Comment: @user6247850 No, worry

Comment: Are you sure the following is true for any non trivial $p$, I believe for the case of positive drift one can show there is a positive probability to hit 0 before i if i is very negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption**: In the following I am going to assume that $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ are independent of each other while $P(X_i = 1) = p = 1-P(X_i = -1)$, so basically $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable taking values either $1$ or $-1$.

**First Remark**: Observe first that the event you are asking for definitly should in some sense depend on the value of $p$, intuitively if $p>1/2$ then the random walk has a much higher chance to up then down and one can easily show with Borel-Cantelli lemma for example that there is a last time that the random walk hits $0$ before heading off to infinity. Hence I am going to seperate both cases:

**Case 1: Biased Random Walk**: Without loss of generality let $p>1/2$ (by symmetry the other case follows aswell) and take some $b<0$ then observe that the probability that you want to calculate satisfies
$$
\sum^{\tau_0 -1}_{n=0} E[1(S_n = b)] = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} E[1(S_n = b) 1(\tau_b < \tau_0)] \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \mathbb E[1(S_n = b) 1(\tau_b < \infty)],
$$
since in order to have a non-zero probability we need to hit $b$ before $0$ and the event $\{\tau_b < \tau_0\} \subseteq \{\tau_b < \infty\}$. I want to proof that the right hand side does not occur with chance $1$ by proving that $P(\tau_b < \infty) =  (\frac{p}{1-p})^b$. Does choosing $b$ negative there some positive chance that $b$ is simply not reached before escaping to infinity, hence by the inequality above the chance is not $1$.

**The right Martingale/Prepartion for OST**: We want to apply the optional sampling theorem, both points can be shown rather quickly:

1. Consider $(W_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where for each $n \in \mathbb N$, one has $W_n = (\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n}$, then it can be easily shown that $(W_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a martingale with respect to the usual filtration.
2. Secondly using the law of large numbers one has $S_n \to \infty$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

**Applying OST**: Applying OST and Monotone Convergence one has

$$
E[W_0] = \lim_{m \to \infty} E[{W_{m \wedge \tau_b}}] = E[\lim_{m \to \infty} W_{m \wedge \tau}] = E[\lim_{m \to \infty} W_{m \wedge \tau_b} 1(\tau_b < \infty)] + E[\lim_{m \to \infty} W_{m \wedge \tau_b} 1(\tau_b = +\infty)].
$$
But since $S_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ almost surely, we know that $E[\lim_{m \to \infty} W_{m \wedge \tau_b} 1(\tau_b = +\infty)]=0$ and hence plugging in the numbers yields
$$
1 =\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{b} \mathbb P(\tau_b < \infty) \implies P(\tau_b < \infty) =  \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^b < 1,
$$
and this finishes the first case.

**Case 2: Symmetric Random Walk**: Checking Durrets book, this is essentially given by an argument via stationary measures (see theorem $5.5.7$ and $5.5.9$) and can be is [nicely formulated and explained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201925/expected-number-of-visits-to-k-before-hitting-0).